# How to print the first two values on the same line, and create another line for the next two and so on

Tags: list, dictionary, for-loop, key

I created a list that contains 3 dictionaries and I want to print the values of the same dictionary in one line, and make another line for the next dictionary.

Using the list below, Im trying to create something that would look something like this:'''

---

```
student1 = {
'name':'Jared',
'gpa' : 3.675
}
student2 = {
    'name' : 'Syallom',
    'gpa':3.322
}
student3 = {
    'name':'Ravee',
    'gpa':3.12
}
stuClass = [student1, student2, student3]
```

---

the output should be something like this using the stuClass list:

```
Jared        3.675
Syallom      3.322  
Ravee        3.12
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
student1 = {
  'name':'Jared',
  'gpa' : 3.675
}
student2 = {
  'name' : 'Syallom',
  'gpa':3.322
}
student3 = {
  'name':'Ravee',
  'gpa':3.12
}
stuClass = [student1, student2, student3]

for student in stuClass:
    print(student['name'] + "\t" + str(student['gpa']))
```

Comment: @Faikar Is it correct this code? If yes please accept the answer.